# while deleting record, transition to another route fails

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm fairly new to ember.js and I'm doing some experiements.  I recently hit a bit of a wall when trying to delete records.  Here is my editing route (from which I call delete)

```
App.PostsEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){
    return App.Post.find(params.id);
  },
  exit: function() {
    this._super();
    tx = this.get('currentModel.transaction');
    if(tx)
      tx.rollback();
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model){
    controller.set('content', model);
  },
  events: {
    save: function(post){
      post.one('didUpdate', this, function(){
        this.transitionTo('posts.show', post);
      });
      post.get('transaction').commit();
    },
    cancel: function(){
      this.transitionTo('posts.show', post);
    },
    destroyPost: function(context) {
      var post = context.get('content');
      post.deleteRecord();
      post.get('store').commit();
      this.transitionTo('posts.index');
     }
  }
});
```

So I have a link through which I trigger destroyPost.  The record is successfully deleted, and I start to transition to the index route, but an error occurs...

Uncaught Error: Attempted to handle event `rollback` on  while in state rootState.deleted.inFlight. Called with undefined

After this, loading the models for the index page stops and I get an empty page.  I can provide any additional code required.  Here is the index route.

```
App.PostsIndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return App.Post.find();
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model){
    controller.set('content', model);
  }
});
```

I should note that both of these routes load correctly by themselves.  It's only in transition that I get failure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to bind to `didDelete` like you did with `didUpdate` in save method.

```
destroyPost: function(context) {
  var post = context.get('content');
  post.one('didDelete', this, function () {
      this.transitionTo('posts.index');
  });
  post.deleteRecord();
  post.get('transaction').commit();
 }
```

Also, your code seems a bit inconsistent: in the save method you're committing a separate transaction, while in `destroyPost` you are committing the whole store.

Comment: This worked.  I pulled the code from elsewhere; I'm just trying to learn at this point.  Should have read through the docs better, though.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.